# My application crashes on device

Tags: objective-c

i am new to iphone development and currently i am working on client server applications but the application run and work good on simulator but when i try it on device then the application crash after some times .Now i dont know why this will happend because i release every object which are decalre with alloc or init.but still crash on device . My application are like (Rate My puppy application)which are store on apple store . please help me if any one have the solutions .

Comment: try to use Instruments or Clang Static Analyzer and see if you get any bugs. Also enable NSZombie. Check google or stackoverflow on these keywords and you will find plenty of infos.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly trying to access an object that has already been released. The simulator seems to be more forgiving in this respect. Do you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message on the console?